# Visual Studios Express 2010 Just Downloaded and installed, Linker Errors when compiling

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, linker

Sorry if my title is a bit ambiguous, but I've been doing all my c++ programming on Linux using g++ at my schools computers and have decided that I want to start doing my c++ at home. I have windows on my home computer and want to write my c++ on that. So I download Visual Studious version "Visual C++ 2010 Express". I'm not sure if this was the correct one, but I assume it is.

After downloading and installing, I wanted to test it so I tried compiling a simple "Hello World" Program, except it gave me this compiling error: `fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt`

After doing a quick not so thorough research and found that downloading and installing the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 might fix it.

I did that am am now getting a different but similar error. `fatal error LNK1108: cannot write file at [Hex Number]`

I can't seem to find any solution to this. Both errors are Linking Errors and have to do with a file. I just barely download VS 2010 Express and the only changes to it that I've made is downloading that Service Pack. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried reinstalling + deleting all files after uninstall?

Comment: No, I thought about trying it, but I literally just installed it and on the very first script I tried to compile, I got the first error I mentioned above. I uninstall and re-install if that might fix it.

Comment: First, Visual Studio 2010 is rather ancient, the current version is 2013. Second, can you please post your code and the exact, non-redacted errors?

Comment: Oh, I thought that 2013 Cost, but now that I look at it, it looks free. Ill try that.